# Compare vector<T>::iterator with vector<T>::reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I am working on an exercise where I have a vector and I am writing my own reverse algorithm by using a reverse and a normal (forward) iterator to reverse the content of the vector. However, I am not able to compare the iterators.

```
int vals[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
vector<int> numbers(vals, vals + 10);

vector<int>::iterator       start = numbers.begin();
vector<int>::reverse_iterator end = numbers.rend();
```

I have a previous algorithm for reversing the vector by using two iterators, however in this task I am not able to compare them using the != operator between them. My guess would be to get the underlying pointers or indexes in the vector with each other but how do I get the pointers/index?

Comment: For your exercise, it would be easier to use two forward iterators: `for (vector<int>::iterator i = numbers.begin(), j = numbers.end(); i < j; ++i) { --j; std::iter_swap(i,j); }`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do a comparison using the the iterator returned by [`base()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base): `it == rit.base() - 1`.

Comment: Be careful, though. If `rit` is an end iterator (i.e. the end of the reverse iteration), then `rit.base()` is `numbers.begin()` and it's UB to subtract 1 from it. An alternative is to compare `distance(numbers.begin(), it) == distance(rit, numbers.rend()) - 1`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: and of course, there is also the issue that `- 1` cannot be applied to BidirectionalIterators in general but only to RandomAccessIterators, so the code provided by @wilx does not work for `list`.

Comment: suggest removing the random-accessible requirement by `it==std::prev(rit.base())`

Comment: @exa: This is an answer to a specific question involving vector iterators. While in general it might be a good idea to do it your way, it is not necessary in this instance. I am sure most people will manage to make the generalization on their own.

Answer (score 10):

You can convert a `reverse_iterator` to `iterator` by calling [`base()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/base/).

Be careful however, as there are some caveats. @Matthieu M.'s comment is particularly helpful:

> Note: `base()` actually returns an `iterator` to the element *following* the
>   element that the `reverse_iterator` was pointing to.

Comment: Note: `base()` actually returns an `iterator` to the element *following* the element that the `reverse_iterator` was pointing to.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Yep, that's the primary caveat I was going to write about - but now that you already did, I don't think I have to anymore. Thanks!

Comment: @TobySpeight: you are right, so I now did exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base

```
rit.base()
```

returns a 'normal' iterator.

Answer (score 2):

The two types cannot be compared (which is a very good idea) and calling `.base()` is not very elegant (or generic) in my opinion.
You can convert the types and compare the result. 
Taking into account the off-by-one rule involving `reverse_iterators`.

Conversion from `iterator` to `reverse_iterator` need to be explicit (fortunately), however, conversion from reverse_iterator to iterator is not possible (unfortunately).
So there is only one way to do conversion and then make the comparison.

```
    std::vector<double> vv = {1.,2.,3.};
    auto it = vv.begin();
    auto rit = vv.rend();
//  assert( it == rit ); // error: does not compile
    assert(std::vector<double>::reverse_iterator{it} == rit);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(&*start == &*(end - 1))` to directly compare the address that the iterator is pointing to.

Comment: You can... but should you? :)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP asked how to compare an iterator to a reverse_iterator, not how to compare addresses of start and end-1 elements.