# how to manipulate data using STL iterator and reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am using STL to reverse a string in place. Normally, I can do it with for loop and i j as index, or with pointer directly. But this time, I want to use STL iterator. I created one forward iterator and one backward iterator. However, it seems I can not compare the two iterators, error shows at "iter != riter" . At meanwhile, I can not use *iter = *riter either. The *iter is not changeable.

Could anyone help me to correct my code, to make it run? Thanks.

```
vector<char> str_reverse( vector<char> input)
{

    vector<char>::const_iterator iter;

    vector<char>::reverse_iterator riter;

    for(iter = input.begin(), riter = input.rbegin(); iter != riter; iter ++, riter++)
    {
        char temp = *iter;

        *iter = *riter;

        *riter = temp;

    }


    return input;


}
```

Comment: It's because iterator and reverse-iterators are not the same. Instead start with two normal iterators, one from the beginning and one from the end. And once you're done with this exercise, throw it away and use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare vector<T>::iterator with vector<T>::reverse\_iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202978/compare-vectortiterator-with-vectortreverse-iterator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<char> str_reverse(vector<char> input)
{
    vector<char>::iterator iter, riter;

    if (!input.empty())
        for(iter = input.begin(), riter = input.end(); iter < --riter; ++iter)
        {
            char temp = *iter;

            *iter  = *riter;
            *riter = temp;
        }

    return input;
}
```