# cant dereference out of range vector iterator- What's the problem?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I tried to realize factorial using vectors. Result's assumed to append the `vector<int> Res`

```
 //corrected
 vector<int> Res;
 vector<int> Fact;

   for(int i=1; i!=4; i++)
        Fact.push_back(i);

int result=1;
  for (auto i = Fact.rbegin(), auto e= Fact.rend(); i != e; ++i)
      result *= *i; 

Res.push_back(result);
```

The problem is in iterators.  Exception: can't dereference out of range vector iterator.
I can't understand what's iterator out of range? `Beg` and `End` was defined after filling the `Fact`. So, what's the problem? I'm only the beginner, I must have missed some impotrant detail in this topic)

Comment: You both decrement `End` and subtract `i` from it. Maybe you mean `*(End-1)`.

Comment: No,  I meant *(End-i) to reach the end of for( ;End != Beg; End--).

Comment: But you also do `End--`. You are double counting. And `*(End-i)` by itself doesn't decrements `End` so it's not needed for your condition to reach `true`.

Comment: I think you would be better off using `rbegin`.

Comment: @SergeyA comparing iterator and reverse iterator requires one more step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15203045/3365922

Comment: Can you explain how to fix it or how to realize it otherwise?)

Comment: @Konstantin Just do `End-1` instead of `End-i`, like the answer below suggests and like I mention in my comment. `--End` already takes care of moving the iterator in the right direction.

Comment: Note that since `result` starts at 0, the final result is always 0 (because you only ever do `*=`).

Comment: Thanks evrebody! End-1 is what i needed)

Comment: @user3365922 OP doesn't need to compare iterators with reverse iterators.

Comment: You edited the code so that the answer that you accepted doesn't make any sense. Don't do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah really next time I won't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`End` is iterator to after the last element, you shouldn't dereference it (`End-i` is `End` when `i` is 0):

```cpp
for (int i = 0; End != Beg; End--, i++)
      result *= *(End-i);
```

I guess you need this:

```cpp
for (; End != Beg; End--)
      result *= *(End-1);
```

Comment: @Konstantin Or you could use reverse iterators (`rbegin()` and `rend()`). Yes this works. But it is not the answer that should be accepted as it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution preserving semantics is to use [reverse_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

```
for (auto i = Fact.rbegin(), e = Fact.rend(); i != e; ++i)
   result *= *i;
```

Alternatively, using [accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
result = std::accumulate(Fact.rbegin(), Fact.rend(), 0, [](int a, int b) { return a * b; })
```

Alternatively, with C++20 and [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges):

```
for (int i : std::ranges::reverse_view{Fact}) 
    result *= i;
```

Alternatively, since multiplication is commutative, any of the above methods with forward iteration.

Alternatively, since multiplication by 0 yields 0 for any number and you start with 0:

```
result = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `end()` returns "one past the last element".  In your first pass,
   `i == 0`, so "one past the end minus zero equals kaboom".
2. If you happen to know that you're dealing with a vector/contiguous memory, you can just `someVec[length-n]`, so long as you know the result is a valid index (n <= 0 or n >= size would both be bad).  For this code, I wouldn't use iterators at all.

Comment: Wrong with regards to end iterators. All bidirectional iterators are decrementable, and all containers (including maps and lists) provide bidirectional iterator.

Comment: I did some digging, and you're absolutely right.  Where the hell did I get that idea?  Some bad ol' implementation of STL from 15+ years ago perhaps.  Huh.