# Does the STL offer something to find the last element for which a predicate is true in a range defined by two non-reverse iterators?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, find

In my code I've been using [`boost::algorithm::find_if_backward`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Misc.html#algorithm.Misc.misc_inner_algorithms.find_if_backward) on some range, but at some point I also needed to use it on some sub-range, expressed in terms of the `[first, last)` iterators.

Eventually I realized `boost::algorithm::find_if_backward` also offers the overload for that, but initlially I was searching on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), expecting that the STL offers a `find_if_backward` function.

Using reverse iterators is not viable, as the iterator I have to get, has to be compared with non-reverse iterators. This, for instance, cannot complile.

```cpp
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,0,0,0};
    auto it = std::find_if(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), [](auto x){ return x != 0; });
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != it; ++i) {
        // whetever
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,0,0,0};
    auto it = std::find_if(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), [](auto x){ return x != 0; });
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != it; ++i) {
        // whetever
        //                   ~ ^~ ~~
        //                   |    |
        //                   |    std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >
        //                   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >

    }
}
```

Am I a bad searcher? Or maybe there's a simple alternative I can't see?

Comment: why does it matter that they are non-reverse iterators? (note that there is [`make_reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator))

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202978/compare-vectortiterator-with-vectortreverse-iterator

Comment: Think of the STL not as the only algorithms and containers you can use, but as a set of examples for some popular ones.  Write your own to extend it, don't be shy.

Comment: [`std::reverse_iterator<Iter>::base`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base), perhaps?

Comment: @idclev463035818, yes, that's what I needed.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yes, I've been a bad searcher. I looked for the `find`-like function instead of a conversion function. Maybe I was just to much blocked by my expectation that the STL should provide it (just like Boost does).

Comment: read about the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is not easy to avoid it when writing a quesiton, but when it happens it makes it more difficult to find the answer. Always tell what is the actual problem you are trying to solve. It can always be that your current path to a solution is the wrong path

Comment: @JohnZwinck, it's not a matter of being shy, but that reinventing a wheel if a wheel exists already is a pity, no?

Comment: @idclev463035818, I know of that, but some time distilling the problem core is error prone. Plus, the fact that I wanted to search backword and that I needed to compare the resulting iterator with a non-reverse iterator was written in the question already. And the duplicate you suggested addresses exactly that. So why XY problem?

Comment: XY because originally your question was asking for a different algorithm and the code that was supposed to demonstrate the actual problem was missing (the unknown X). Once you included the code it was clear that you need no different algorithm (ie that was your Y). Don't get me wrong, I am not complaining, writing a good question is difficult and as you say, while distilling it is easy to end up with a XY.

Comment: @idclev463035818, no worries, thanks.